# Integration Non-linear PDE problem

Tags: integration

[Original Image for question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTHPw.png)

> $$f'\left( f''+\frac{1}{3}\eta \right) =0$$

Hi, does anyone know how to integrate this?

My first concern is whether i can cancel out that additional $f'$

Comment: Welcome to math.se! Please read [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and edit your post accordingly. Obviously, this equation doesn't look like a PDE, but rather like an ODE. Where is it from? Is $\eta$ a constant?

Comment: Is $\eta$ a constant, or the independent variable? And if it's the latter, why didn't you use $\aleph^{(0)}_1$, instead?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $\eta$ is a constant,
$$f'\left( f''+\frac{1}{3}\eta \right) =0$$
$$f' f''+\frac{1}{3}\eta f' =0$$
Integrating
$$\frac{(f')^2}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\eta f =C$$
now, we can simply solve for $f'$
$$f'=\sqrt{C-\frac{2}{3}\eta f}$$
renaming $\frac{2}{3C}\eta=c$
$$\frac{f'}{\sqrt{1-cf}}=\sqrt{C}$$
integrating:
$$-\frac{2\sqrt{1-cf}}{c}=x\sqrt{C}+C_1$$
$$f=\frac{1-(c\frac{x\sqrt{C}+C_1}{2})^2}{c}$$
$$f=3C\frac{1-(2\eta \frac{x\sqrt{C}+C_1}{2C})^2}{2c\eta}$$
this equation is rather unordinary, in what context did it arise?